# Object Volume Calculation/Estimation

Tags: object, opencv, detection, volume, kinect

I'd like to calculate or at least estimate the volume of an object that is placed in front of a camera/kinect. Any idea of where should I start from? Do you recommend OpenCV? Do you recommend any other technology such as sonar/laser?

Answer (score 4):

Been writing a project on hand recognition in OpenCV 2.3, and an essential part of this, was to know exactly what features we wanted to extract, and from what object?. When you say you want the volume, you will of course need to work in 3d space, or make some pretty harsh assumptions. In terms of the kinect, you will of course be working in 3d space but single angle perspective will yet again force some big assumptions.

I made a little example in paint. Shown below
[image]

White areas of an object, is the perceived angle with no depth information.
Blue is perceived agle with depth information.
Red is no information at all.

In the first example you won't even know whether it is a sphere or a circle, so volume calculation will be close to imposible, unless you know that you are working with spheres.

In the second example, a kinect is used, giving us a depth information on only half of th sphere, i would be resonable to assume that this perceived half-sphere is infact a sphere, and double the volume calculated from the current information.

Last exaple is multi angular. I've used a similar method to track a water bottle rocket in 3d space. I will give a depth perception to some degree. But I think a similar approch could be used with multiple kinects, giving a very detailed set of data.

What I'm tryig to get at here is... know the types of object you will encounter, find out what you are willing to sacrifice in hardware and setup to get more precise data, and be sure to make reasonable assumptions based on former.

Hope answer was usefull (and that my time spent in paint was worth it :D )

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV is definitely worth looking at, but if you're really focused on 3D processing I would recommend checking out the [Point Cloud Library](http://pointclouds.org/) (PCL). It has far more features specific to 3D processing than OpenCV does. But, both projects are run by Willow Garage, so there should be more integration between the two as time goes by. The PCL will integrate quite easily with the Kinect, so you can get started quickly. [Here](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/) is a good list of tutorials to get you started.